# ReportViewer pagination based on Grouping on Rownumber expression

Tags: .net, rdlc, report-viewer2010

[image]I have created a Group on rows based on the following expression in my Report:

```
=Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/5)
```

What is happening on the report is, I am getting only the first record of every group (and not all records in that group). Also on the Toolbar Pager, when the report initially comes, it shows: `1 of 2 ?` and then when I click on "Next" button, it shows `2 of 3 ?` and so on keeps on increasing like this pattern.

I am very new to reporting, and I don't know from where this Question Mark is coming and why its not showing all the records in the group.

Thanks for any help.

> UPDATE [1 Day after posting] :-

I have figured it out now, why its happening, the problem is: There are RowGroups attached to the Report that are not getting deleted. When I click on "Advanced" in the bottom pane of Visual Studio, it shows: `Column Groups` and `Row Groups`. In a fresh new report, when I drag a `Table`, the `Row Grops` contain less number of Items then are here. I have tried deleting the Group by opening its XML View, but then Visual Studio crashed.

Any body knows how to delete the `Group` from `RowGroups` ? This might solve the problem.

Comment: I also ran into this issue in VS2012 where groups were not being properly removed from a report. My only solution was to re-create the report in a new RDLC file.